# Obtener datos de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagrid

¿Como puedo obtener datos de un DataGridView? Tengo un objeto llamado dgvPersonas de tipo DataGridView, le cargo datos, se muestran correctamente en la tabla y ahora quiero recuperar esos datos. Especificamente seleccionar una fila, para luego obtener una columna de dicha fila. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour revisa este enlace para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y además, dale click a este otro: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que veas cómo es que se puede preguntar correctamente de tal manera que aumentas la calidad de tu pregunta y generas que más desarrolladores podamos ayudarte. Saludos y bienvenido al sitio :D

Comment: `String Nombre = dgvPersonas .CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();` //Cells[0] indica la coumna que quieres obtener el valor

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que estaba buscando hacer. MUCHAS GRACIAS LUIS!

Comment: @LuisFernando pon tu comentario como respuesta para que Pedro Rout la marque como respuesta válida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el valor de la fila selecionada solo haz esto:

```
String Nombre = dgvPersonas .CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(); 

//Cells[0] indica la coumna que quieres obtener el valor
```

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente:

```
DataGridView dgvPersonas = new DataGridView();

//Recorre las filas..
foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dgvPersonas.Rows)
{
    //Accede a la columna que quieras, o las recorres todas con otro foreach...
    DataGridViewCell columna1 = fila.Cells[0];
}
```

Comment: Puedes explicar un poco la respuesta. Asi la gente aprendera el proque y no se dedicaran a copiar y pegar solo.

Comment: He puesto los comentarios, poco más hay que comentar. Creo que si se busca un poco está más que explicado, adjunto enlace de Microsoft por ejemplo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Perdona @A.Martin , estoy tan acostumbrado a trabajar con comentarios que lo he omitido al leerlo :S

Comment: No hay problema @GDP! :)